# Symfony2, Doctrine2 update row without ID (this table is with only "one" row)

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I want to create my entity **Settings**, which will have basic editable information about my page. I've created my entity <kbd>Settings.php</kbd> with this source:

```
<?php
namespace Acme\SettingsBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @ORM\Table(name="settings") 
 */ 
class Settings
{    
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
     */ 
    protected $page_name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
     */
    protected $page_description;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
     */
    protected $page_email;                  
}
```

and I do not know, how to tell in my controller that will be only overwriting existing data, not creating new. This is my controller <kbd>AdminController.php</kbd>

```
public function indexAction(Request $request)
{
    if (false === $this->get('security.context')->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')) {
        throw new AccessDeniedException();
    }

    $settings = new Settings();

    $form = $this->createForm('settings', $settings);
    $form->handleRequest($request); 

    if($form->isValid())
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($settings);

        try {
            $em->flush();
        } catch (\PDOException $e) {
            // sth
        }
        $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add(
            'success',
            'Settings was successfuly changed'
        );
    }

    return $this->render('AcmeSettingsBundle:Admin:index.html.twig', array('form' => $form));
}
```

I didn't test it, but I believe, it creates a new Settings object with new data. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always set some field to act as an ID, even if it meant to be dummy.

Assign some default value that you will always use and then you should be able to update your settings with no problem.

Usually, DBMS wars you about absence of unique identifier so same applies to Doctrine.

```
$settings = new Settings();
$settings->setId(Settings::DUMMY_IDENTIFIER); // const within class

# rest of the logic
# ....
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$em->persist($settings);

try {
    $em->flush();
} catch (\PDOException $e) {
}
```

You could take another approach: persist every property as a single row. However, you would need to build more complex form type and execute more queries.

**EDIT:**

You could use raw SQL but that is less flexible:

```
# raw query
$sql = "UPDATE settings SET page_name = ?, page_description = ?, page_email = ?";

# data
$params = array( $settings->getPageName(), $settings->getPageDesc(), $settings->getPageEmail());

# must specify type due to protection against sql injection
$types = array(\PDO::PARAM_STR,\PDO::PARAM_STR,\PDO::PARAM_STR);

# execute it
$stmt = $this->getEntityManager()->getConnection()->executeUpdate($sql, $params, $types);
```

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/data-retrieval-and-manipulation.html#using-prepared-statements

Comment: Yes, I thought about it, but there is not better way? Without adding redundant fields?

Comment: I have edited my answer with raw SQL solution that does not rely on ID field.

Comment: Yes it looks more strange. I'll try look something on the google and wait for other ideas. If there aren't, i'm force to use ID field. Thanks for now.

Comment: I'm not sure, if i use setId() it will throw an exception of unique key and if i don't set it to unique/primary, i think, it will create a new row too. Maybe `$em->getRepository('AcmeSettingsBundle:Settings')->find(Settings::DUMMY_IDENTIFIER)` will work correct.

Comment: yes, in order to do that you need to: `find()` the entity, `setId` on the new one and `merge` it ;)

Comment: why set and merge? Just find and working with current object and doctrine will automatically detect if update or insert

Comment: Yes, in case you are passing **managed** object to your form. Otherwise, I think, merge is needed

Comment: i used this method for editing other objects without merge and worked

Comment: Excelent :) Glad to hear that ;) So, after all, you went for the solution via `DUMMY_IDENTIFIER`?